# Count number of users/entries in people picker using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-2010, peoplepicker

Think of this scenario,
If I add two user entries to people picker(multiple selection is permitted) field.
I need to count these entries using java script/Jquery(Output what i want is: 2).
how can I do this. Is there any built in methods??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#idOfPeoplePicker div.ms-inputuserfield>span.ms-entity-resolved').length
```